# Vue child component not rendering

Tags: vuejs2

I have 2 components:

```
Vue.component('page', {
  props: ['pages'],
  template: '<li>{{ pages.title }}</li>'
})

Vue.component('block', {
  props: ['blocks'],
  template: '<div>{{ blocks.id }}</div>'
})
```

"Page" is the Parent component, and "Block" the child component.

Both of the components contain a loop through an array:

```
<page v-for="page in pages" v-bind:pages="page">
    <block v-for="block in blocks" v-bind:blocks="block"></block>
</page>
```

The "Block" component is not being rendered at all, while it is when placed outside of the parent "Page" component. I feel like I am missing something obvious, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the block component in the list of components for the page component.

```
var block = {
   props: ['blocks'],
   template: '<div>{{ blocks.id }}</div>'
});

Vue.component('page', {
   data: function () {
     return {
       pages: [{title: 'Some title', blocks: [{id: 1, {id: 2}, {id: 3]}]
     }
   },
   components: {
     block: block,
   },
   props: ['pages'],
   template: `<li>{{ pages.title }}<block v-for="block in page.blocks" v-bind:blocks="block"></block></li>`
});
```

Then use the page component like:

```
<page v-for="page in pages" v-bind:pages="page"></page>
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working. I am getting "Unknown custom element: <block>". I also feel like this solution isn't quite right, I would like to keep both as separate components if at all possible.

Comment: They are still separate components, the only difference is that block is now registered locally.
If you rather keep what you have so far, then you should change the way you use page and block components. What is between the <page> tags will be replaced by what you have defined in the template attribute, so your block component will never be displayed. You should change the template of page to use the block component in it.

Comment: I found this JSBin: https://jsbin.com/boluhe/3/edit?html,js,output This does what I want, without the loops. Is it only possible with static components?

Comment: You can use the for loop in the sub component

Comment: When using your code I get "Property or method "page" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". I assume this is from the page.blocks, should be different?

Comment: Do you have a property pages in the data of your page component? If not, you should create one and give it a value.

Comment: The data comes from the main App var, which it is loaded in with a getJSON call in the beforeCreate function.

Comment: I have now fixed it by using inline components. I will mark your answer as correct, as I'm sure it would work with the correct data. Your answer gave me a lot more insight on how things work, and I'm sure I will find a nice solution from here. Thanks!